# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*Но сначала нужно чтобы что-то поменялось внутри.*

Answer (score 4):

Но сначала **нужно, чтобы** что-то поменялось внутри.

Запятая ставится, это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, союз ЧТОБЫ, опорное слово "нужно" с модальным значением.